Artin map is the Kronecker symbol
Let $d$ be a squarefree integer. Then the discriminant $\Delta$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is either $d$ or $4d$. I know that a prime number $p$ is ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ if and only if it divides $\Delta$.
Let $p$ be an unramified prime number. I would like to show that the Artin map in this case equals the Kronecker symbol:
$$
\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\mid \mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{d}{p}\right),
$$
which equals the Legendre symbol if $p$ is odd, and depends on $d\bmod 8$ if $p=2$.
I think somewhere in the proof one needs to show that $p$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ if and only if $p$ is a quadratic residue, and $p$ is inert if and only if $p$ is not a quadratic residue. I would like an explicit proof of this fact.


one needs to show that $p$ splits in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ if and only if $p$ is a quadratic residue, and $p$ is inert if and only if $p$ is not a quadratic residue.

That should be covered in any algebraic number theory textbook. The decomposition of primes in a quadratic field is the most basic example of working out how primes decompose.  That you're asking us about the Artin map but you're not sure how a prime decomposes in a quadratic field has me worried that you have never actually worked out some real examples in your study of algebraic number theory. Have you?
When $K$ is a number field in which $\mathcal O_K$ has the form $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ (a power basis for the ring of integers), and $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, the way a prime $p$ decomposes into prime ideal factors in $\mathcal O_K$ is related to the way $f(x) \bmod p$ decomposes into irreducible factors.  Do you know that when $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ the integers of $K$ do look like $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is closely related to $\sqrt{d}$?
